# Java compiler can't find my Scanner variable

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Read
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new java.io.File("textfile.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        }        
        while(scan.hasNext()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] elements = line.split(",");
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I get

```
error: cannot find symbol
        while(scan.hasNext()){
              ^
  symbol:   variable scan
```

?

Comment: My "Votes Cast" page shows that I don't do improper things like that.

Comment: Fair enough.  You do know the post you just replied to is 3 1/2 years old, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the scope.  You can *declare* the `Scanner` object outside of the `try...catch` block, and *instantiate* it inside of it.

It's definitely also the case that you would want to put all of your I/O operations that depend on the `Scanner` being instantiated inside of the `try...catch` too, or you'll run into issues later.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("textfile.txt"));
        // other I/O operations here including anything that uses scan
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("helpful error message", e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it but now i get error: variable scan might not have been initialized
 while(scan.hasNext()){

Comment: Declare and instantiate the variable to `null` then.  Although that scares me a bit - if you move all of your I/O operations inside of the try portion of the `try...catch`, you shouldn't run into that issue.

Comment: I just followed your advice and put my code in the try block and it works now (surprisingly)

Answer (score 0):

Your `scan` should be declared outside the `try-catch` block, or you can put `while` loop in `try-catch` block

Comment: Be sure to set `scan` to null where you declare it, of you'll still get errors.

Comment: Or *inside* the try/catch block ... along with your while loop.  It doesn't make sense to scan if you got an exception, does it?  So putting it inside the loop is definitely reasonable.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 Good point, thank you very much.. l learned a lot from this question though I'm not the author of it..

Answer (score 0):

Changed the place of the where loop.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Read
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new java.io.File("textfile.txt"));
         while(scan.hasNext()){
          String line = scan.nextLine();
          String[] elements = line.split(",");
         }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is absolutely correct.  It looks like some idi0t came through and downvoted everybody.  Probably didn't take his/her meds :)  C'est la vie...

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Read
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan=null;
    try 
    {
       scan = new Scanner(new java.io.File("textfile.txt"));
       while(scan!=null)
       {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] elements = line.split(",");
       }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){ }        
}
}
```

Comment: If that file doesn't exist, your code blows up since you're dereferencing null.

Comment: ...no you didn't.  Keep at it, you'll get it soon. :)

Comment: Never play "whack-a-mole" with Makoto - he's too quick on the draw :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Read
{
    private static final String TEXT_FILE = "textfile.txt";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // BAD
        try {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(new java.io.File("textfile.txt"));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          ; // Eating exceptions - a bad habit :(
        }        
        while(scan.hasNext()){
          String line = scan.nextLine();
          String[] elements = line.split(",");
        }
    }
}
```

In contrast ...

```
class Read
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Good
        try {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(new java.io.File(TEXT_FILE));
          while(scan.hasNext()){
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] elements = line.split(",");
          }
        } 
          catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println ("Error parsing " + TEXT_FILE + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you redeclare the variable?  Variable shadowing definitely takes effect here.

Comment: @Duli-chan - I agree.  In this case, declaring "Scanner scan" inside the try/catch block is best.  I changed the code accordingly :)